# Pillagers don't attack anymore in Minecraft Java Edition update 1.17

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft Java Edition on my PC, update 1.17. My OS is Windows 10. I play alone in my survival world on Normal difficulty with no mods.

Before the 1.17 update, Pillagers kept attacking me. In Survival Mode I always have a base with stone walls around it. They typically come near my base and shoot me. Even if they didn't approach my base, they would wait in areas near my base. By killing them I would get the Bad Omen effect, which causes a raid when approaching a village. I looted their leader's flag and crossbows.

After the 1.17 update, I didn't see a single Pillager attacking my base. Did the mechanism change? Is this a bug and should I report it? Did anyone encounter this issue and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As of reading through the [Changelogs](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/sections/360001186971-Release-Changelogs) for *1.17.1 - 1.16 JE*, no tweaks were made to Pillager Patrols seem to have been made. I've had them spawn in my 1.17 worlds too, so either it's a bug or you just happen to not have any Pillagers spawn lately.